Difference of infinite measures
Let $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure and consider $A,B\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(B\setminus A)=0$. Then, I can write:
$$\mu\left((X\setminus A)\setminus (X\setminus B)\right)=\mu(X\setminus A)-\mu(X\setminus B)=$$$$=\mu(X)-\mu(A)-\mu(X)+\mu(B)=\mu(B)-\mu(A)=\mu(B\setminus A)=0$$
I wonder if this is correct even if $\mu(X)=+\infty$, is it?

It's true, but your proof doesn't work since it potentially involves $\infty-\infty$ which is undefined. Instead, it is possible to prove that $(X\setminus A) \setminus(X\setminus B)=X \cap (B\setminus A)$ from which the claim follows.

Thank you very much!

By expanding the initial measured set with de Morgan's laws, we get:
$$(X/A)/(X/B)=(X\cap A')\cap(X\cap B')'=$$
$$(X\cap A')\cap(X'\cup B)=X\cap B\cap A'=$$
$$(X\cap B)/A$$
Which shows that
$$\mu((X/A)/(X/B))=\mu(B/A)$$
Whenever $B\subseteq X$, without regards for the nature of $\mu$ or $X$.
Also, note that if $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a measure space over $X$, then:
$$\mu(A/B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)\Leftrightarrow A=S\cup B$$
Where $S$ is any set that satisfies $S\in \Sigma\wedge S\cap B=\emptyset$.
